# Disqus comment count not working

Tags: javascript, wordpress, disqus

I installed Disqus manually in a WordPress theme (didn't work at all via the plugin). It works fine, but I'm having trouble displaying the comment count.

I think I'm doing a lot of things right tough:

The link on the /blog/ page looks as follows:

```
<a href="/the-post-title/#disqus_thread" data-disqus-identifier="dq-332" title="The Post Title"><i class="fa fa-comment"></i> 0</a>
```

The comments.php:

```
<?php if (comments_open()) : ?>
<div id="disqus_thread"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    /* * * CONFIGURATION VARIABLES: EDIT BEFORE PASTING INTO YOUR WEBPAGE * * */
    var disqus_shortname = 'myshortname'; // Required - Replace example with your forum shortname
    var disqus_identifier = 'dq-<?php echo get_the_ID(); ?> ';

    /* * * DON'T EDIT BELOW THIS LINE * * */
    (function() {
        var dsq = document.createElement('script'); dsq.type = 'text/javascript'; dsq.async = true;
        dsq.src = '//' + disqus_shortname + '.disqus.com/embed.js';
        (document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] || document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]).appendChild(dsq);
    })();

    alert(disqus_identifier);

</script>
<noscript>Please enable JavaScript to view the comments.</noscript>
```

As you can see I'm alerting the disqus_identifier and therefore can verify it's being set correctly (in this case `dq-332` as above)

And I am loading the count.js globally with

```
<script type="text/javascript">
/* * * CONFIGURATION VARIABLES: EDIT BEFORE PASTING INTO YOUR WEBPAGE * * */
var disqus_shortname = 'myshortname'; // required: replace example with your forum shortname

/* * * DON'T EDIT BELOW THIS LINE * * */
(function () {
var s = document.createElement('script'); s.async = true;
s.type = 'text/javascript';
s.src = 'http://' + disqus_shortname + '.disqus.com/count.js';
(document.getElementsByTagName('HEAD')[0] || document.getElementsByTagName('BODY')[0]).appendChild(s);
}());
</script>
```

I only got it working under one (faulty) circumstance:

Before I tried it with the `data-disqus-identifier` it worked by appending #disqus_thread to the permalink without trailing slash, so e.g. `http://mydomain.com/the-post-title#disqus_thread`

The problem with that was that comments there wouldn't show up in `http://mydomain.com/the-post-title/` and `http://mydomain.com/the-post-title/#disqus_thread` (same with the trailing slash, as generated by WordPress everywhere).

That's why I ended up with the identifier approach after all. Which doesn't have any effects so far. Would be happy about any type of hint. Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Was not able to solve it this way. Spent some more time investigating why the WordPress plugin didn't work. Worked it out in the end.

Note: you shouldn't have any relative URL plugins activated with disqus.

Comment: So could you tell me what the problem was? I am having the same issue.

Comment: Okay I found out that it does not work locally, but works on our server. The JavaScript simply adds the number of comments followed by a space to the InnerHtml of your anchor tag.

Comment: In my case it was a plugin incompatibility with some relative URL plugin